# I need to vectorize this operation in python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, loops, vectorization

i have an array containing 0,1,2,3 numbers 
like that 
[1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0...]
i need to replace all "0" with the number preceeding the zeros.
i need to have this. 
[1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,...]
can i do this using vectorization and without using loop. 
my list is too big and that is the most time consuming part of the code
thanks in advance

alternatively you may offer a better way to loop 
i am doing this now

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
if df["poz"][i]==0:
    df["poz"][i]=df["poz"][i-1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pandas ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) method after replacing 0 by nan:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0] )
s.replace(0, np.nan).ffill()
```

Result:

```
0     1.0
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     3.0
5     3.0
6     3.0
7     3.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    2.0
11    2.0
12    2.0
dtype: float64
```